# Accessing mysql dbase with MysqlWorkBench on VirtualBox (Vagrant - ZF - BoilerPLate)

Tags: php, zend-framework, virtualbox, vagrant

Does anyone know hot to connect to VB MySQL via MysqlWorkBench. I can log in in virtual box via terminal, but I can not connect it throught MySqlWorkBench. Also I can ping google on vb, ifconfig gave me 10.0.2.15 address, and when I enter it in MysqlWorkBench I got error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at 10.0.2.15:2222 with user davs
```

My Virtual box use port 2222 for connecting. Also when I try to connect with ip 127.0.0.1

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at 127.0.0.1:2222 with user davs     Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at 127.0.0.1:2222 with user davs
```

Any advice will be helpfull, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure user 'davs' exist in MySQL with the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes, davs exist as user. I solved it few minutes ago. Solution is:There is a line inside the MySQL configuration file that limits MySQL connections to localhost only. So the first thing we need to do is to remove (or comment out) that line.

Open the MySQL server config file at /etc/mysql/my.conf and look for the line that says:

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment it out by adding a hash (#) at the front:

#bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Great that you solved your problem!

Comment: @davs, this didn't solved the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 14):

This looks like an old question but since I just ran into the problem, here are the settings that I used on MysqlWorkbench to get everything working on my mac:

- Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
- SSH Hostname: 127.0.0.1:2222
- SSH Key File: /Users//.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
- Mysql Hostname: 127.0.0.1
- Mysql Server Port: 3306
- Username: root
- Password: vagrant

Your settings may be slightly different but the key part is using the insecure private key as was mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'insecure private key' located at: `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`